# Create flash projector exe with custom icon on build in Flashdevelop

Tags: build-automation, flash, flashdevelop

For some projects developed using Flashdevelop we want to deliver a Flash Projector executable with a custom icon instead of a swf. I'm looking for ways to automate this, and is wondering if someone has a better solution than what we're currently doing:

- Build a release version .swf in Flashdevelop
- Open the .swf in the release version of the standalone flash player
- Select File -> Create Projector and enter a name (*really* annoying that the flash player doesn't suggest the same file name but with an .exe extension instead)
- Open the program GConvert and select Tools -> Modify icons in EXE/DLL
- Browse to the .exe file and select ok
- Select the icon to replace
- Browse to an icon file and select ok

Half of the steps involve swapping out the exe icon, maybe someone has a simpler way of doing that?

I should point out that for some projects we have used Zinc, which allows you to generate an .exe with a custom icon. But other than that Zinc is far from automated and we really don't want to take the Zinc route when a Flash Projector will do the job just as well.

The solution doesn't have to be 100% automatic, running a batch-file once the .swf has been generated would still be a huge improvement.

Anything that could point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.